# Better way to dynamically create HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I need to dynamically create HTML form. So I can to it using 2 approaches:

1) Use JS to create form

```
  var myId = document.createElement("input");
  myId.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  myId.setAttribute("name", "myId" + index);
  myForm.appendChild(myId);
```

and so on..

2) Use `innerHTML` and writing valid HTML code:

```
    document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML += 
'<input type="hidden" name="myId' + index + '"/>';
```

What approach is better? What is usually way to dynamically create form? For me second approach is more readable

Comment: The first is ***much*** faster.

Comment: i would suggest to use [_templates_](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for anything longer than a few lines of dynamic html. But for small pieces the second is more readable <my opinion>

Answer (score 0):

Creating dynamic forms by concatenating string in javascript becomes unmanageable as the HTML size begins to grow.
The recommended approach is to use a template engine to create dynamic HTMLs.
[Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is one of the more popular template engines out there.
There's also a [site](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) that helps you choose a template engine for your need.

Answer (score -1):

second approach is the best because it gives you the possibility to verify the exact composition of the page. at least in my opinion.

Comment: This is incorrect. Second approach is incredibly slow and should be avoided to use. If you need more visibility use templates, as [@amdixon suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976494/better-way-to-dynamically-create-html-form#comment29737308_19976494).